# Excel, using Visual Basic Whilst Running a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA code whilst running a macro in Microsoft Excel.

I am running a macro by "RecordMacro" in excel.

During the macro, I need to use some VBA code. To do this I click Visual Basic and then use some VBA code.

During the macro, the VBA code works as specified, but then when I click stop recording and try and run the macro it misses out completely the VBA part.

The VBA code is already stored in my workbook before I start the macro so I don't see this as a copying and pasting problem.

To try for yourself write a list of numbers in a column, Record and macro and try and execute the below code.

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    'Updateby20141106
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim xCol As Integer
    Dim xArr As Variant
    xTitleId     = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type: = 8)
    xRow         = Application.InputBox("Rows :", xTitleId)
    Set OutRng   = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
    Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
    xCol         = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
    ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        iRow = i Mod xRow
        iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
        xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

Comment: When you record a macro it only records what is happening on the front end. If you record a macro, run some code, and then inspect the recorded it won't show the code that was executed as that's already written... which is how you executed it. What are you trying to do here? Also to clear some potential confusion, a Recorded Macro is VBA. It records your actions on the front end and writes that as VBA. You already have the VBA that is doing the action here though so it's not clear why you would want to record it.

Comment: Perhaps you are just wanting to assign this `Sub SplitColumn()` to a hotkey? Or perhaps you want to edit this `Sub SplitColumn()` code to work against a specific column when it's run? Please help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Looks like the code is from the below site. What's wrong with their existing guide? 
[link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2244-excel-split-long-column-into-multiple-columns.html)

Comment: There code is fine. My problem is that I am recording a macro I do a bunch of data sorting/filtering tasks, then I want to use their code during the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted a module and pasted the above code into it.

I then input two cells, `A1 = "1,1"` and `A2 = "1,2"`.
Next I recorded a macro that did a flash fill of that series to A30. In the macro, I also set the typeface to bold and then stopped recording.

I opened the module the macro was recorded in and added the line `SplitColumn`. Running the recorded macro resulted in executing the first couple steps, then running the SplitColumn subroutine, then finishing the macro. Bottom line being that you can call a sub or function from another sub.

```
Sub flashfill()
'
' flashfill Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A30").Select
    SplitColumn
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, but how does the SplitColumn code know which cell to place the values and how many columns to split it into. Say I needed them in H22 and split into 4

Comment: @TonyChivers I can't speak for the KuTools code's function as I didn't program that. I was only hoping to illustrate that you can run a sub from another sub.

Comment: @TonyChivers There is absolutely a way to fix the rows and columns, probably several ways depending on your needs. I'd recommend researching creating a range object that refers to the cells you're interested in. If you need help with that, it's probably best for you and the rest of the community to ask another question. Good luck!